# Hide delivery counter in weekend

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript, to display a countdown on my shop, counting down to the next dispatch.

I really would like to hide in the div completely in the weekend, instead of displaying "2 days, 2 hours ......"

Also, i can't figure out how to display different shipping times for each day in the week.

Here's my current code:

```
<script>
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
setInterval(function () {  
    var now = new Date();    
    var missedTodaysDelivery = now.getHours() >= 14 ? 1 : 0;
    var end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + missedTodaysDelivery, 14, 0, 0, 0);

    var lastCall = new Date(end);
    lastCall.setDate(now.getDate() + (5 - now.getDay()));

    if (now > lastCall) {
        end = new Date(lastCall);
        end.setDate(end.getDate() + 3);
    }

    var diff = new Date( end - now );
    diff.setTime( diff.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * diff.getTimezoneOffset() );

    var result = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> Vi afsender om ";
    result += diff.getDate() - 1 == 0 ? "" : diff.getDate() - 1 + " dage ";
    result += diff.getHours() == 0 ? "" : addZero(diff.getHours()) + ":";
    result += diff.getMinutes() == 0 ? "" : addZero(diff.getMinutes()) + ":";
    result += addZero(diff.getSeconds()) + "";

    document.getElementById('wc_countdowntimer').innerHTML = result;   
}, 1000);
</script>
<div id="wc_countdowntimer"></div>
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to the weekend problem is to not do anything if today is saturday or sunday.

```
if(new Date().getDay() % 6 === 0) {
    setInterval(function() {
        // your code
    }, 1000);
}
```

`date.getDay()` returns a numeric value between `0 (Sunday)` and `6 (Saturday)`. Either of those `% 6` equal `0`.

Comment: Thank you. I still can't get it to work properly. I guess it's a bit more complex than I imagined, as the counter will need to be hidden, from friday at 2PM when we dispatch until sunday 24 hours before the next dispatch on monday.